# How do you make a string converted to a variable name instantiated inside of a function global?

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

Sorry for that confusing title, in my function my parameter is the name I want I want to set as a global variable name. I can do this outside of a function, and I can instantiate a global variable without a string as its name, and I haven't found any other articles with a solution to both problems at the same time.

```
def myFunc(varName):
    temp = varName
    # global vars()[temp]  <== This line produces the error
    vars()[temp] = 5  # varName becomes a local variable
```

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. Can you try to add to the post what your goal is, instead of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Store the values in a dictionary with "variable name" as keys. Then you can replace or add values to it using something like `var_dict[varName] = 42`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function to achieve this:

```
def set_global_var(name, value):
    globals()[name] = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_global_var('foo', 3)
    print(foo)
```

Note that this is most of the case not a good idea. You might want to use a global `dict` object instead and simply assign new keys to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `global`, like so (notice that `some_text` is unknown before the call to `fun1`):

```
def fun1():
    global some_text
    some_text = "1234"

def fun2():
    print(some_text)

fun1()
fun2()
```

This produces `1234` as one would expect, see [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/hLKerJ).

---

So, in your case just go for

```
def myFunc(varName):
    global TEMP
    TEMP = varName
```

Question remains: why would you want to do that? Don't clutter your global namespace with variables only a class/function needs.

Comment: I don't see any relation of this answer to the OP. He is passing some variable he wants to "make global" or something.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa: See the edit, was about to write something.